# How to do an URL rewrite that works with a pre-existing .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a forum that is currently accessible through the URL:

`www.website.com/index.php?app=forums`

Instead of that, I would like people to be able to go to:

`www.website.com/forum`

Here's the kicker, though - there is already a .htaccess file with the following contents:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

It seems like this should be possible, but I'm not sure how to do it myself.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but something like this should work. Add this just before the first RewriteCond directive.

```
RewriteRule ^forum$ /index.php?app=forums
```

Alternatively, you could also do a 301 redirect from /forum to the index.php URL.

By doing this:

```
Redirect 301 /forum "http://www.website.com/index.php?app=forums
```

However, it looks like you want a proper rewrite so the 1st option is better,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried adding the line below `RewriteBase /`, but it doesn't work. Also, I don't want to do a redirect, because I actually want people to access the forum through this URL.

Comment: I don't have an apache setup at the moment but you could try doing a 301 redirect:

`Redirect 301 /forum "http://www.website.com/index.php"`

Add that right at the top of your .htaccess file. Also, this should help you know if apache is actually even using the .htaccess file/mod-rewrite, type in a URL that doesn't have a file/directory associated with it like website.com/blahblahblah and see if it redirects you to index.php. Might be worth it ;)

Comment: I see you changed your get params in the question. Updated the answer to reflect that.